# refresh the relationship without reloading the model

Tags: php, laravel

I have this situation:

1 .$model = Model::where(someCondition);

After that code above I  do some updates to $model child relationship, model has settings relationship so I update them and save them to db.

Then I try later to access $model->settings and I only get the settings that where there when I did (1) above and not all the settings that i just added and saved to db.

I find my self having to after doing some updates to settings, to do this again so it loads the new settings that have been added to db table.

so I repeat this line
$model = Model::where(someCondition);

to be able to do this $model->settings and get fresh data from db.

Is this how it has to be done or is there a way to refresh relationship so it gets latest data from db instead of using data from when I first created the model?

Hope you understand what I mean.

here is some code:

```
    $tBlock = TemplateBlock::set($template_id, $blockData, $parentId);

    // remove settings from db that have default values
    foreach ($tBlock->getSettingsNoDefaults() as $baseKey => $value) {
        if(!array_key_exists($baseKey, $blockData->settings)) {
            $tBlock->removeSetting($baseKey);
        }
    }

    // only save settings that have been customized by user
    foreach ($blockData->settings as $key => $setting) {
        $tBlock->setSetting($key, $setting['value'], $setting['type']);
    }

    // refresh the block so we get latest settings
    $tBlock = TemplateBlock::where('tblock_id', $template_id);
    $settings = $tBlock->settings;
```

setSetting function looks like:

```
public function setSetting($key, $value, $type = 'string')
{
    $setting = $this->settings()->updateOrCreate(
        ['key' => $key],
        ['key' => $key, 'value' => $value, 'type' => $type]
    );

    return true;
}
```

notice i have to get tBlock again by doing:

```
$tBlock = TemplateBlock::where('tblock_id', $template_id);
```

that gives me what I am after, but it feels so not elegant, is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$model->load('relationship')` will lazy eager load the relationship anew.

[Docs 5.4 - Eloquent - Relationships - Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)