# laravel foreach doesn't load the latest saved data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to make a shopping cart using laravel 7 and ajax. When i press add product, it save the product into the cart in the database. If the product is already in the cart, it will just add 1 to the quantity. If not, it will create a new order item in the cart. Then, it will return an output variable with html content through json response. Then i append the html data using javascript. The problem is when i add a product and the product isn't in the cart so it created a new order item. The json response doesn't seem to load the latest order item in the html. But when i add that same product the second time, it managed to append the html. Does the foreach didn't get the latest data from database?

This is the function in the controller

```
public function addItem($product_id, Request $request){
    $order_id = auth()->user()->waitingOrder->first()->id;
    $order = Order::find($order_id);
    $bingo = false; 
    foreach ($order->orderItems as $key => $order_item) { 
      if ($product_id == $order_item->product_id) {
        $order_item->quantity = $order_item->quantity + 1;
        $order_item->save();
        $bingo = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if ($bingo == false) {
      $new_item = new OrderItem();
      $new_item->order_id = $order_id;
      $new_item->product_id = $product_id;
      $new_item->save();
    }
    $output = "";
    foreach ($order->orderItems as $item) {
      $output .= '<tr>'.
      '<td align="left" width="15%">'.
          '<img style="height: 80px; width: 80px;" src="'. asset('img/products/' . $item->product->image) .'">'.
        '</td>'.
        '<td align="center" width="20%">'.
          $item->product->name .
        '</td>'.
        '<td>'.
          rupiah($item->product->price) .
        '</td>'.
        '<td width="14%">'.
          '<input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" value="'. $item->quantity .'" min="1" max="'. $item->product->stock .'">'.
        '</td>'.
        '<td>'.
          rupiah($item->product->price * $item->quantity) .
        '</td>'.
        '<td>'.
          '<a href="'. route('kasir.remove.item', $item->product->id ) .'" class="remove-btn">'.
          '<span class="icon_close"></span>'.
          '</a>'.
        '</td>'.
      '</tr>';
    }
    return response($output);
  }
```

This is the javascript code

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-btn', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            success:function(data){
                $('#orderItems').html(data);
            }
        });
    });

    function order(){
        var customer_name = $('#customer_name').val();
        var link = $('#order-btn').attr('href');
        if (link != '#') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: link,
                data: {name:customer_name},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#order_id').val(data.order_id);
                    $('#customer_name').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#order-btn').attr('href', '#');
                    $('#cart-total').html("")
                    $('#cart-total').html(data.output)
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know laravel or php but I can see that your foreach only works for `$order` and this variable only returns some object if it finds it in db. When you create new object and save it into the database you use `$new_item`. So your foreach doesnt know anything about new row... even if its saved into database. I think you should just use `$order` instead of `$new_item` in your  `bingo==false`

Comment: `$order->fresh();` or `$order->refresh();` after saving the order item. Depending which version of laravel you are using.

Comment: `$order->load('orderItems');` Might be more specific. Both explained and answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642950/how-to-reload-refresh-model-from-database-in-laravel) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192035/refresh-the-relationship-without-reloading-the-model)

Comment: @sonic I use $order as a shopping cart, and in $order there are $orderItems in which i store the product_id. So if want to add a product, i have to store it in $orderItems. $new_item is an object of $orderItems. I can't put the product_id in $order.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are not to be generating html in controllers, you should use views for that part, this is not best practice in any form.

Comment: @user3647971 Thank you so much. I add $order->refresh() and it works. I'm guessing when i create a new order item, $order still contains the data before i  made the new product. So when i put foreach() it doesn't contain the new one. Thanks to everyone for the reply.